# Spline interpolation in interp1 without filling nan values in

Tags: matlab, interpolation, spline

I have tide observations each 5 min, I want to interpolate it into a 1 min interval.

I tried to do it in Python but it takes too much time, so I have moved to MATLAB. The problem is that the spline method fills NaN values.

The image below explains the problem, I want to have a spline interpolation without the NaN values being filled. How can I chance my `interp1` function to do so?

[image: the image explain it]

```
file='NANTES_5min_nan.txt'
[date, hauteur] = lecture_hfs(file);
vect=[date(1):1/24/60:date(end)];
h_interp=interp1(date,hauteur,vect,'spline');

h_interp_lin=interp1(date,hauteur,vect,'linear');
```

the second figure is from Python interpolation. the results are good but unfortunately it's only for 1 month data. when I want to apply it for the whole data (17 years) the execution never ends   [here is the link for python figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylZn3.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `vect` directly as query points, you can replace the values of `vect` which are near a `NaN` value in `hauteur` by `NaN`. This can be done by using another (linear) interpolation:

```
temp = date; % copy of the original dates
temp(isnan(hauteur))=NaN; % set the values which are NaN in hauteur to NaN
h_interp = interp1(date,hauteur,interp1(date,temp,vect),'spline'); % the inner interpolation results in vect with NaNs where appropriate
```

A bit messy and there might be more elegant ways, but I was fascinated by the possibility to solve this by nesting another interpolation.

Comment: thank you @Leander, it works fine. i have thought to add these two lines after interpolation done : ` idx=find(isnan(h_interp_lin));   h_interp(idx)= nan ;`  to remove filled NaN values by interpolation but I prefer your method.

Comment: This would work too of course. You could skip the `find()` tough, it wouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Yes it's true, I'm not used to code with MATLAB. But it's a great opportunity to begin doing it.   Have a nice day